# Getting counts of a specific list of labels from a Neo4j result set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database that for business logic reasons has semi-redundant labels for a feature count. For example, if a `foo` node has three instances of a feature, it would have the labels `featureCount0`, `featureCount1`, `featureCount2`, and `featureCount3`, among other unrelated labels that relate to different static inherent attributes of `foo` (which also has numerical property values assigned).

As part of my overall process, I'm trying to get the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) of a feature count among the `foo` children of a given parent node `bar`. My draft query looks like

```
MATCH (u:bar)
WHERE ID(u) = 927646 // Target bar ID for testing
WITH u
MATCH (u)-[:PARENT_OF]-(l:foo)
RETURN 
    COUNT(l:featureCount0) AS feature0,
    COUNT(l:featureCount1) AS feature1,
    COUNT(l:featureCount2) AS feature2,
    COUNT(l:featureCount3) AS feature3,
    COUNT(l:featureCount4) AS feature4,
    COUNT(l:featureCount5) AS feature5
```

Mysteriously, all the feature counts come out to be the same number, and that number is greater than the total count of `l:foo` in the result set. I am very clearly not counting what I think I'm counting.

If it's really not tractable I can hop out to Python and do it there, but I'd like to minimize language hopping in my overall process. Since `foo` has multiple other unrelated labels, I'm not interested in any method that simply spits out a list of all labels on `foo` -- I'm interested only in this specific subset of labels and, in fact, actively do not want information about the others at  this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COUNT` does not care if the value it is counting happens to be a boolean `true` or `false` -- it will happily count all values.

This query may work for you. It minimizes the number of DB hits by looking up the nodes of interest once.

```
MATCH (u:bar)-[:PARENT_OF]->(l:foo)
WHERE ID(u) = 927646 // Target bar ID for testing
WITH COLLECT(l) AS foos
UNWIND RANGE(0, 5) AS i
RETURN i, REDUCE(s = 0, x IN foos | CASE WHEN 'featureCount'+i IN LABELS(x) THEN s + 1 ELSE s END) AS count
```

The result will look like this (with some made-up counts):

```
╒═══╤═══════╕
│"i"│"count"│
╞═══╪═══════╡
│0  │52     │
├───┼───────┤
│1  │50     │
├───┼───────┤
│2  │47     │
├───┼───────┤
│3  │41     │
├───┼───────┤
│4  │33     │
├───┼───────┤
│5  │9      │
└───┴───────┘
```

Comment: That totally works, and I'm going to mark it as the answer, but if I have children of `foo` in my query the count suddenly jumps up. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: You are probably evaluating some `foo` nodes multiple times. Try using `COLLECT(DISTINCT l)` instead. Do not use `DISTINCT` unless necessary, since it takes additional overhead to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
 WITH u
 RETURN 
 SIZE ( [(u)-[:PARENT_OF]-(l:featureCount0) | l]) AS feature0
```

and so on?